# My android app crashes after getting killed by task manager , How to resolve that?

Tags: android

my problem: if my app is going to be destroyed by a task manager on the phone, after restart the app it show me Force close . in my app in calling WebServices in BackGround, when i Kill my app using Task Killer and i Start my app again it shows me Force Close .

Actually i want when app is killed by Task Killer i want to show loing Screen ,can any buddy tell me any solution for that .
Thanks in advance

```
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.palewar.coinop/com.palewar.coinop.NewTransaction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:861)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:619)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at com.palewar.coinop.NewTransaction.onCreate(NewTransaction.java:855)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-03 17:40:55.801: E/AndroidRuntime(4825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: Welcome to the reason google advises against Task Killers in the first place. A lot depends on how the Task Killer invokes the kill order. What you need to do in order to get the appropriate help is post the logcat with the error and let us see your onCreate(), on Resume(), onDestroy() and whichever method(s) is relevant to the error.

Comment: here comes the importance of logging in your project.  i don't think you will find any given api to use when Task Killer kills your app. 
You should log down every thing and see where exactly things are getting stucked. 
In the end you will have to change your code to make sure it uses fresh resources and fresh task start at every app launch.

Comment: @ Fuzzical Logic  im not able to see logcat can u please tell what i have  to write in onCreate,onResume or onDestroy . let me try in which method is relevant to write.

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html this should you getting started with logcat. If you are working with eclipse there should be a logcat view somewhere and it should give you a stacktrace at the moment your app crashes. Please copy the stacktrace into your question to enable us to help you.

Comment: i have this in my logcat when im getting Force close.

Answer (score 0):

Line number 855 of NewTransaction.java is trying to access something that no longer exists.

You should check whatever object you are using is not null and re-create it if it is.